# IE8 console log - stub if dev tools not open, but use if dev tools is open?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, console

I'm using the following stub to protect against leaving console.log statements in a production application:

```
//  Protect against IE8 not having developer console open.
var console = console || {
    "log": function () {
    },
    "error": function () {
    },
    "trace": function () {
    }
};
```

This works fine in the sense that it prevents exceptions from being thrown when I call console.log in IE8 without the developer tools open. However, I dislike the fact that if I open dev. tools after the code has loaded -- I still don't see my log messages.

Is it possible to have both? My attempts have led me to infinite recursions of console.log calls. I also found this: http://log4javascript.org/ but I'd rather not unless entirely necessary

**EDIT:** To clarify: I simply want to not throw an exception if dev. console isn't open, but use the console if it is opened later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do something like:

```
if (typeof(console) === "undefined") {
   var console = { 
      log: function() { },
      error: function() { },
      trace: function() { }
   };
}
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding the question. This JavaScript is the first line to run in my program. The dev. tools are not open yet. So, console gets stubbed out. Then, a moment later, I open up the dev. tools. console.log remains stubbed out even though I can now use it successfully.

Comment: Without making a custom function, don't think its possible.  You can detect for developer tools, but at that point the variable is already overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Make a wrapper function and call it instead of `console.log`.

```
function log(msg) {
  var console = window.console;
  if (console && typeof console.log === 'function') {
    console.log(msg);
  }
}
```

This way, it is not going to override `window.console` and make it not available later.